# Combining two functions into a single function

Tags: python, function

Good Day,

I would like to combine these two functions into a single function. I've tried just writing out the code as a single function and it doesn't execute the last piece of code at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

```
def times_table_input(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
            return multiple_int
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")


def times_table_input2(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
            return multiple_int
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")

result = times_table_input * times_table_input2
        print(times_table_input , "times", times_table_input2, "is equal to",  result)
        return result
```

Comment: Have you tested `times_table_input`? Does it work? Have you tested `times_table_input2`? Does it work?

Comment: Both do work, I would just like to combine the times_table_input and times_table_input2 functions into a single function.

Comment: When you execute, you will end up with error...

Comment: Is there a reason you need two separate functions? Why can't you call `times_table_input` twice?

Answer (score 0):

```
def times_table_input(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
            return multiple_int
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")
```

You only need one function. When you call it assign its return value to a variable/name.

```
>>> n1 = times_table_input('number? ')
number? 5
>>> print(n1)
5
```

If you want to multiply two numbers call it a second time.

```
>>> n2 = times_table_input('number? ')
number? 6
>>> print(n1,n2)
5 6

>>> result = n1 * n2
>>> print(result)
30
>>>
```